# How to keep my player moving as long as the button is held down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a sort of momentum based platformer where you cant change direction or move in the air as a mobile game,

I am not the best at C# so forgive me if this is a stupid question,

I am using buttons from the canvas as my input, and I want my player to keep moving as long as the buttons are held down but I seem to have to keep tapping to make the player to move

```
enter code here using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerController : MonoBehaviour
{
private float moveSpeed;
private float jumpSpeed;
public bool onGround = true;

private Rigidbody2D playerRb;



// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    moveSpeed = 100;
    jumpSpeed = 3;


    playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}

void onCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Level")
    {
        onGround = true;
    }
} 

public void MoveLeft()
{

    if (onGround)
    {
        playerRb.AddForce(new Vector2(-moveSpeed, 0), ForceMode2D.Force);
    }
}

public void MoveRight()
{
    if (onGround)
    {
        playerRb.AddForce(new Vector2(moveSpeed, 0), ForceMode2D.Force);
    }
}
```

}

as you can see I have created 2 different functions for my button to activate when they are clicked

Is there anyway that I can make it so these function will keep going as long as the button is pressed down?

Comment: Is `onCollisionEnter` a typo here? Otherwise it will never be called .. it needs to be `OnCollisionEnter`

Comment: yeah it was a typo thanks for spotting that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set velocity of rigidbody when you get your button down and when you get your finger up set velocity to zero. It is a pretty simple implementation. I would also recommend to check how it is done in CorgiEngine for example.

Comment: thanks, It makes so much sense know, I don't know why didn't think about it earlier but how do I detect when the button is up. So far I use the On click system on the button to make my character move is there also like an on release button

Answer (score 0):

You will need some custom button that can actually do that.

E.g. something like

```
[RequireComponent(typeof (Button))]
public class ContinuousButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private Button button;

    private Coroutine coroutine;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        Reset();
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        Reset();
    }

    private void Reset ()
    {
        if(!button) button = GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    private void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // Not really doing anything but required for OnPointerExit to work
    }

    private void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        if(coroutine == null) return;

        // cancel the routine if pointer leaves button
        StopCoroutine (coroutine);
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // optionally only take left mouse button and ignore the rest
        if(pointerEventData.button != PointerEventData.InputButton.Left) return;

        // Start a new continuous routine which will simulate a click each frame
        coroutine = StartCoroutine(WhilePressed(pointerEventData));
    }

    private void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        if(coroutine == null) return;

        // cancel the routine when letting go of the button
        StopCoroutine(coroutine);
    }

    private IEnumerator WhilePressed (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // This is fine in a Coroutine as long as you yield inside 
        while(true)
        {
            button.OnPointerClick(eventData);

            // Tells Unity to "pause" the execution here
            // render this frame and continue from here
            // in the next frame 
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Simply attach this to the same `GameObject` as the `Button` component and it should convert it into a continuous (hold down) button which basically calls `onClick` listeners every frame.